# Can't read php file output with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to submit a variable from a form to an ajax request of a php file, and output the contents of the php file to a div.
Here's my main file:

```
<div>
    <form name="zipform">
        <p style="color:#cccccc;">Enter your Zipcode: <br><input type="text" name="zipcode">
            <input type ="Button" Value="Search Providers" onClick="showAndClearField(this.form)">
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function showAndClearField(frm)
{
var zip = frm.zipcode.value;
    frm.zipcode.value = "";

    $.ajax({
        url: "testphp.php?zipcode="+zip,
        success: function (data) {
            document.write("content of the executed page: " + data);
            $("#result").html(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            if (xhr.status > 0) document.write("got error: " + status);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Here's the testphp.php file:

```
<?php
$zipcode = $_GET["zipcode"];
echo '<div><p>'.$zipcode.'</p></div>';
?>
```

The above results in a blank page of "got error: error"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe you should prepend the ajax url script with slash

Comment: It would help to output the "error" parameter in your error function -- that should be a textual description of the error. Also, consider looking into learning how to use your browser's built in debugging tools; they can speed up tracking problems like this down a lot. Most browsers these days will easily let you see the Ajax requests being made, and their results and errors.

Comment: The error was "Not Found", so I changed the URL to the full URL of the file, and now the script don't run at all. - I'm using chrome currently but I'm not sure how to track any errors down..

Comment: Using firebug I was able to find this:

When I click on the form button it reports:  Reload the page to get source for: http://www.myurl.com/testphp.php

Comment: Just as a side note, since you use Chrome: open [inspector](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) and its Console tab and use `console.log` to do the debugging. E.g. `console.log(xhr, status, error)` in your error method.

Comment: Thanks now I'm getting somewhere.  Error: 'No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present'

Thank you all this lead me to the answers that I needed, and am moving forward now.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do..

```
<?php

 if (isSet ($_GET ['zipcode']))
 {
    $zipcode = $_GET["zipcode"];
    echo '<div><p>'.$zipcode.'</p></div>';
    exit;
 } 
?>
```

html

```
<div>
    <form name="zipform">
    <p style="color:#cccccc;">Enter your Zipcode: <br><input type="text" name="zipcode" id='zipcode'>
        <input type ="Button" Value="Search Providers" id="getZip">
    </p>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready (function (){

    $("#getZip").on ("click", function (e){
        var zip = $("#zipcode").val ();

        $.ajax({
            url: "test1.php",
            data: {zipcode: zip},
            type: "GET",

            success: function (d) {
                document.write("content of the executed page: " + d);
                $("#result").html(d);
            },

            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                if (xhr.status > 0) document.write("got error: " + status);
            }
        });

        e.preventDefault;
    });
 });
</script>
```

Kinda my way of doing it, yet it works wonders.

Answer (score -2):

try `$.get`
this is easier

```
$.get(
   'testphp.php',{'zipcode':zip}
).done(function(data)
{
$("#result").html(data);
})
```

you want send get method without var

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Now the message is saying: (for zip 999999)

Reload the page to get source for: http://www.myurl.com/testphp.php?zipcode=999999